# Can “however” be used in middle of a single clause?

Tags: discourse-markers, appositives, however-placement

(Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I really couldn't find a proper answer to my particular problem—either because it's been never answered that way or I don't know the proper term to search.)

*However* is usually used at the beginning of a statement. But is it fine to use it in the middle, like an appositive or adverbial phrase? Eg.,

Accepted version:

> However, my family decided to stay back.

My version:

> My family, however, decided to stay back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *however* is perfectly acceptable both at the beginning of a statement and in the middle. But the placement affects the inference that may be drawn or the emphasis that is created.

Take the following example:

> i). When the signal to board the buses was given, the other families surged forward. However, my family decided to stay back.

Implication: My family decided not to join the rush (e.g. for safety reasons, or to avoid getting separated).

> ii). When the signal to board the buses was given, the other families surged forward. My family, however, decided to stay back.

Possible implication: My family was reluctant to board. (Placing 'my family' at the head of the sentence emphasizes its qualitative difference from the other families.)

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences have a different meaning and suppose a different context.

You version implies that there were other families that decided *not* to stay back, but your family did.

The version with *however* in the beginning of the sentence *might* mean the same, but it may also imply that there were a lot of reasons for my family *not* to stay back, but them notwithstanding, they decided to stay back. There need no other families be involved.

Consider these two fragments:

> 1.a) His grades were low and he was struggling to pass each exam. However, my brother was determined to get his degree.
>
> 1.b) His grades were low and he was struggling to pass each exam. My brother, however, was determined to get his degree. *This does not seem to make much sense!*
>
> 2.a) Most students boycotted the university when the board openly supported the apartheid regime. My brother, however, was determined to get his degree, so he stayed.
>
> 2.b) Most students boycotted the university when the board openly supported the apartheid regime. However, my brother was determined to get his degree, so he stayed.

I would write the a-version of these sentences. Sentence 1.b I find confusing and I would certainly avoid. Sentence 2.b would be understood, but I would certainly prefer version a to describe that situation.